# jQuery .empty() with iframe whose src is a pdf breaks plugin in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

In Internet Explorer 8-10, if I have an iframe whose source is a PDF, and that Iframe is wrapped in a div, and I call `jQuery.empty()` on that wrapping div, there seems to be some sort of interaction between the PDF plugin and IE that causes the plugin to break, become non-interactive (unable to do anything with regard to the document after removal from the DOM), and in some occasions ignore scrolling, floating above the page.

Sample Code:

```
<button id="remove">remove</button>
<div style="height:2000px">
    <div style="height:500px; width:800px;" id="embedDiv">
        <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="somepdf.pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#remove").click(function () {
            $("#embedDiv").html("Some Content!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Working example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/j2e56/

Is there any way to hide/remove this embedded pdf after .empty() has been called? I'm working in an environment where I really don't know how or when my frame will be removed from the page, and I have no control over how it will be removed. I can use setInterval to check periodically whether the iframe is still on the document after the fact, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Setting the `src` attribute on the frame to `''` or `'about:blank'` will work before `empty()` has been called, but it seems to not have any effect afterward which is where I seem to be stuck in this case.

Comment: have you tried calling `.remove` on the iframe instead of `.empty` on the div?

Comment: The issue is I'm in a CMS sort of situation where I don't know who is going to remove me, when they will do it or how they will do it. There are a couple of ways to successfully remove an embedded plugin in IE, but I can't find any that will work *after* the frame is off the dom. The only signal I get that the frame needs to be hidden is after it has been removed.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that. does the `.html("Some content!")` code reside in your files or not? What i was proposing was to replace your `$("#embedDiv").html("Some Content!");` with `$("#embedDiv iframe").remove()` if you have the option

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I have no control over how the iframe is removed. Could be a .html(content), could be a .remove(), could be .empty(), might not be jquery at all. It could be directly on the iframe element, or a parent div somewhere up the tree. I'm trying to figure out whether there is any defensive measure I can take to clean up after this bug once it's triggered.

Comment: ok ok i see, just another thought: try attaching a `onbeforeunload` event to the iframe

Comment: While that is a fantastic idea, IE appears to not allow access to this particular sort of iframe's contentWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't the perfect solution but it works for right now.

The solution would be to attach to onbeforeunload, but the problem is IE won't honor those callbacks once it has been transformed to a pdf iframe. So what I did was add a sort of 'canary' iframe right before the pdf iframe in the document, and attach to unload on that one. When an unload situation is detected, the canary unload callback sets the src to '' on the pdf iframe so it can be unloaded successfully.

Note that this will only work when you use .empty() prior to any call to html().

Edit: This is wrong, it only works if you call it against the iframe's direct parent and not anything above that.